# Local and GMT Time don't give a correct result

Tags: android, simpledateformat, gmt

I'm developing IM app for android, I want to use "Last seen" for the friends to see when there friends went offline.
My Idea is:
**1.** In the client side, When the user leave the App, it will send to the server a special message containing the time in GMT.
**2.** in the server side, the server pass the time as is (gmt) to the friends.
**3.** in the other clients, each client converts the GMT time to his local time.
Here is how I built the message to send:

```
if (Status.toLowerCase().equals("offline")) {
            Status =EsTools.getGMTtimaDate(System.currentTimeMillis());//Important
            EntryActivity.currentOpenChatID = "none";
        }
        Log.d("offline--","will send status = "+ Status);
        OnlineMsg.putExtra("action", "com.__.MESSAGE");
        String nowtime = "" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        OnlineMsg.putExtra(ConstantsGCM.TYPECLM, ConstantsGCM.ONST);
        OnlineMsg.putExtra(ConstantsGCM.STATUS_on_of,Status);// if offline the time in GMT Zone
        OnlineMsg.putExtra(ConstantsGCM.TO_CLM, "-01");

        OnlineMsg.putExtra("V",ver);
       final String Msgid= UUID + nowtime;
        OnlineMsg.putExtra(ConstantsGCM.NAME_CLM,userName);
        final Bundle bndl = OnlineMsg.getExtras();
```

and the getGMTtimaDate() function code:

```
 public static String getGMTtimaDate(long currentLocal) {
         SimpleDateFormat GMTsdfTime =   new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy - ( HH:mm:ss )");
        GMTsdfTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
        String GMTtime=GMTsdfTime.format(currentLocal); //currentLocal=System.currentTimeMillis()

        Log.d("times--","GMT= "+GMTtime);
        return   GMTtime;
    }
```

Now we sent GMT time To the server
the **recipient** will convert the GMT to localTime:

```
String localFromGMT=EsTools.getLocalFromGMT(intent.getStringExtra(ConstantsGCM.STATUS_on_of));
```

the localFromGMT() function code is:

```
   public static String getLocalFromGMT(String GMT) {
        long timeInMilliseconds=0;
        Date LocalTime= null;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat GMTsdfTime =   new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy - ( HH:mm:ss )");
            GMTsdfTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));

            LocalTime = (Date) EntryActivity.GMTsdfTime.parseObject(GMT);// to parse GMT Time
             timeInMilliseconds = LocalTime.getTime(); // GMT in milliseconds
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         SimpleDateFormat LocalsdfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy - ( HH:mm:ss )");
       String local= EntryActivity.LocalsdfTime.format(timeInMilliseconds);// convert to local
        Log.d("times--","Local From... Gmt= "+local);

        return   local;
    }
```

I always got the local time of the sender not my local!
 what is the problem?

Comment: why do you format the time in gmt? why not simply send the time as a long?

Comment: one thing you need to check first: at which point is your date wrong. is it when you format it? when you parse it? when you format it back?

Comment: when I format it back... the strange thing is some times it give me local from GMT and sometimes It give GMT!????? in the same  setuation...
I gonna mad

Comment: can you give actual values from your tests?

Comment: I think that was my fault, until now all is OK, I was covert from GMT twice in two different places in the code..